# How does one compare and validate a specific property value of any item of an array to any string value of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, validation, comparison

I have an array of objects which I receive from the input tag. I want to compare a particular value in the object whether it matches to the array or not.
For example the input takes in multiple files, but i need it to be only of particular formats.
The format is of either png or jpeg.
The below show correct when i am uploading only one file, I want it to work when uploading multiple files at once.

I want to verify whether the whole object contains valid formats, if all the files are of valid format, then the files will be uploaded, and if one of the file format doesn't match, then files will not be uploaded.

Thank you in advance.

target.files gives [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oMXO.png)

```
const IMAGE_TYPES = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];

const handleClick = ({target}) => {
  Object.keys(target.files).forEach((key) => {
    if (IMAGE_TYPES.includes(target.files[key].type)) {
      setIsInvalidImageFormat(false);
    } else {
      setIsInvalidImageFormat(true);
    }
  });
};

<input
   id='icon-button-photo'
   multiple
   onChange={handleClick}
   type='file'
/>
```

Comment: I know it does not give you exactly what you asked for but better use accept attribute  `<input id='icon-button-photo' multiple onChange={handleClick} accept="image/png, image/jpeg">`

Comment: accept="image/png, image/jpeg" doesn't work

Comment: it should. this way you can only upload jpeg or png type file . [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)

Comment: have already tried it, hence posted this question here, mac gives an option to select other types of files when we change the format to all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) as well as [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) are the tools for any boolean based validation of array entries. It also might be easier / better readable to make use of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead of [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) ...

```js
function setIsInvalidImageFormat(isAllValid) {
  console.log({ isAllValid });
}
const IMAGE_TYPES = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];

function handleClick({ target }) {
  setIsInvalidImageFormat(
    Object
      .values(target.files)
      .every(fileData =>
        IMAGE_TYPES.includes(fileData.type)
      )
  );
};
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { bottom: 0; }
```

```html
<input
  id="icon-button-photo"
  multiple
  onChange="handleClick(event)"
  type='file'
/>
<!--
<input
   id='icon-button-photo'
   multiple
   onChange={handleClick}
   type='file'
/>
//-->
```

Comment: is it possible to do it within the handleclick()?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object to an array by getting the values out with:

```
Object.values(<yourObject>)
```

This will produce an array of values which you can then compare. Would that work for your use case?

Comment: the object is an array of arrays

Comment: 'I have an array of objects' was what was said in the question, sorry if I misunderstood

Answer (score -1):

```
To get the values or key first you need to convert it into array.
Actually you are accessing the key which you dont require you need to access the values and then comparing.

const IMAGE_TYPES = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg'];

const handleClick = ({target}) => {
  Object.values(target.files).forEach((value) => {
    if (IMAGE_TYPES.includes(target.files[value].type)) {
      setIsInvalidImageFormat(false);
    } else {
      setIsInvalidImageFormat(true);
    }
  });
};

<input
   id='icon-button-photo'
   multiple
   onChange={handleClick}
   type='file'
/>
```

Comment: While I agree it would make more sense to directly access the values rather than the keys, if you do that, the check should be `IMAGE_TYPES.includes(value.type)` not `IMAGE_TYPES.includes(target.files[value].type)` (which would throw an error)